# How to add time query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment

(

appointID INTEGER,

appoint_date DATE,

appoint_time  TIME,

appoint_type VARCHAR(5),

primary key (appointID)

);

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(1, '15-Apr-2017', '10:00', 'long');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(2, '15-Apr-2017', '10:30', 'short');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(3, '28-May-2017', '14:00', 'long');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(4, '20-May-2017', '15:00', 'short');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(5, '11-May-2017', '10:30', 'long');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(6, '26-Jun-2017', '9:30', 'short');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(7, '30-Jun-2017', '14:00', 'long');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(8, '30-Jun-2017', '15:30', 'short');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(9, '28-Apr-2017', '16:00', 'short');

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(10,'30-Apr-2017', '13:00', 'short');
```

I keep getting this error when I try to add TIME:

```
Error starting at line : 24 in command -

CREATE TABLE Appointment(

appointID INTEGER,

appoint_date DATE,

appoint_time  TIME,

appoint_type VARCHAR(5),

primary key (appointID)

)

Error report -

ORA-00902: invalid datatype

00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I'm also trying to add my DOCTOR TABLE, but I keep getting a Error report

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:**

create table Doctor

(

    appointID   INTEGER     not null,

    regnum  CHAR(6),   

    doc_name    VARCHAR(40),

    doc_gender  CHAR(1),

    qual    VARCHAR(80),   

    foreign key (appointID) references Appointment

    primary key (appointID, regnum)

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion: avoid `CHAR` datatype unless it makes sense (such as in *gender*, as you did), as well as `VARCHAR` >>> use `VARCHAR2` instead (personally, I never use `CHAR`, and have never ever used `VARCHAR`).

`DATE` datatype contains both date and time component, so you're safe if you use it.

Columns that make the primary key constraint don't have to have the `NOT NULL` constraint specified, because primary keys don't allow nulls anyway.

So, here it is, a working example:

```
SQL> create table appointment
  2    (appointid    integer constraint pk_app primary key,
  3     appoint_date date,
  4     appoint_type varchar2(5)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into appointment values
  2    (1, to_date('15.04.2017 10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'long');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create table doctor
  2    (appointid   integer constraint fk_doc_app references appointment (appointid),
  3     regnum      varchar2(6),
  4     doc_name    varchar2(40),
  5     doc_gender  char(1),
  6     qual        varchar2(80),
  7     --
  8     constraint pk_doc primary key (appointid, regnum)
  9    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Good answer, please mention why OP is getting the error message as well.

Comment: Because of a missing comma at the end of this line: `foreign key (appointID) references Appointment`, @user75ponic (if that's what you asked).

Comment: OP has used `TIME` as `datatype` which doesn't exist in Oracle if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @user75ponic, Rehan has already said that in his answer; that still stands, so ... yes, I agree & you're not mistaken :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no data type called 'TIME', you can use timestamp :

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
appointID INT,
appoint_date DATE,
appoint_time timestamp ,
appoint_type VARCHAR(5),
primary key (appointID)
);
```

For insert you have to use TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP functions, as what you are inserting is string.:

`INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(3, To_date('15-Apr-2017','DD-MON-YY'), TO_TIMESTAMP('10:00','HH24:MI'), 'long')`;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59f5ef

Comment: Thanks, I'm now getting an invalid month error when I try to insert the data into the appointment table. Any idea how to fix this? Thankyou

Comment: Can u give the putput of this : `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'`

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: Good answer @RehanAzher