# How to add Time to Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

[image: Output of Appointment insert]

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment
(

appointID INTEGER,

appoint_date DATE,

appoint_time  TIMESTAMP,

appoint_type VARCHAR(5),

primary key (appointID)

);

INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES(3, To_date('15-Apr-2017','DD-MON-YY'), TO_TIMESTAMP('10:00','HH24:MI'), 'long');
```

I'm trying to add the time to my appointment table but it keeps adding `01/APR/18 + the time` (which is unnecessarily long) as seen in my picture. I just want it to show `'10:00'`

Comment: A `date` in Oracle always includes the Time part (quite missleading name) and a `timestamp` is almost the same, just adding fractional seconds. You only need the `appoint_date`

Answer (score 0):

Referring from your earlier question [How to add time query in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715988/how-to-add-time-query-in-oracle) , you don't need to store time as a separate column(`appoint_time`). In Oracle, `DATE` can store time as well.

In your `INSERT`, you could have written `TO_DATE('15-Apr-2017 10:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')` and avoided the `appoint_time` column.

So, viewing your time component  as a separate column  would require you to use `select TO_CHAR(appoint_date,'HH24:MI') as time` ,

Another option to view this component within the date column is to change your `NLS_*`  parameters and view the date along with time in the same column.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YY HH24:MI'
```

Now, while you do `select * FROM Appointment` your date column will display both date and time